# zindex not working in IE

Tags: css

I have div with tranparent drop down,it acts as suggest box.Below this i have two input boxes.Whenever i call this suggest box,it overlaps other two input boxes. iam trying to control this using zindex property and position elements,But is is not working.

Any help appreciated.Thanks in advance.

After applying z-index,i didn't see my controls in jsp page.
Below is the code:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="2">firstname</td>
<td colspan="2"><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' style='position:relative;float:left;'>
<tr><td width="25%" style="position:relative;z-inedx:999'>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
</table></td></tr>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">lastname</td>
<td colspan="2"><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' style='position:relative;float:left;'>
<tr><td width="25%" style="position:relative;z-inedx:1'>
<input type="text" name="lastname">
</table></td></tr>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2">middlename</td>
<td colspan="2"><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' style='position:relative;float:left;'>
<tr><td width="25%" style="position:relative;z-inedx:1'>
<input type="text" name="middlename">
</table></td></tr>
</td>
</tr>
```

On chnage of firstname value ,i am displaying div content,it overlapping other two input controls.
Regards,
Raj

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems to be using z-inedx.

Comment: good one... true thought... Funny that nobody else noticed.. :P

Answer (score 2):

You spelt `z-index` incorrectly: you have written `inedx`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post some code? Also make sure that all of the elements you are trying to utilize z-index on are positioned (they are using the position attribute {relative, absolute}), z-index only works on positioned elements.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar questions at [bgiframe with jQuery UI 1.8.9 Dialog and jQuery 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043675/bgiframe-with-jquery-ui-1-8-9-dialog-and-jquery-1-5). You need to set the parent element to `position:relative`, and also give it a `z-index` similar to the suggest box which is a child element. This will do the trick for IE.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When i had this issue, `Position:relative;` worked for me. you need to set that also.

Answer (score 0):

Z-index is only compatible with sibling elements.  Is that your issue?